# Configure URL Rewrite in nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite, files

Im trying to set up URL Rewrites for my MVC Framework but as this is the first time i have used Nginx I am having a little trouble.

I have 2 access points for my application:

- `/index.php`
- `/admin/index.php`

I need to route the URL for those folders / access points to the according index file, for example:

- `/admin/auth/login/` >>> `/admin/index.php?/auth/login/`
- `/contact/` >>> `/index.php?/contact/`

This is what I have so far:

```
#Project
server {
listen 7000;
listen localhost:7000;

    location / {
        root   /srv/www/htdocs/ASDDL/;
        index index.php;
    }

    location /admin/ {
        root   /srv/www/htdocs/ASDDL/admin/;
        index index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_index    index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/htdocs/ASDDL/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Now as you can see that i think the problem lies with the following line:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/htdocs/ASDDL/$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Where it's not routing to the admin folder because it tries to route to the root `index.php` file, can anyone shed some light on the correct way to do this?